# why is TypeScript telling me "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'" when neither of those are true?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to rewrite a js file into ts for one of the first times. I am new to TS and do not recognize all the various syntactical issues. However, it also looks ... pretty good to me.

So why this error?

```js
function processAmount(number: number, displayedInFeed: boolean): string {
        // turns "2707" -> "2,707" and "306438" -> "306k"
    const amtAsString: string = number.toString();
    if (amtAsString.length <= 3) {
        // handles values like "123" and other 3 digit nums
        return amtAsString.toString();
    } else if (amtAsString.length === 4) {
        // converts "1234" -> "1,234"
        return amtAsString[0] + "," + amtAsString.slice(1);
    } else if (amtAsString.length > 4 && amtAsString.length <= 6) {
        // "306903" -> "306k"
        return amtAsString.slice(0, 3) + "k";
    } else if (amtAsString.length > 6) {
        // "65,730,395" -> "65.7m"
        let mil: string = " million";
        if (displayedInFeed) {
            mil = "m";
        }
        let millionLvlString: string = amtAsString.substring(0, amtAsString.length - 6) +
        "." +
        amtAsString[amtAsString.length - 6] +
        mil
        return millionLvlString
    }
}

export default processAmount;
```

Error:

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/path/to/file/ProcessAmount.ts(12,82):
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.  TS2366

    10 |  * Purpose of function is to convert 10,000 => 11.3k, 101,000 => 101k, 1,000k => 1.00m, and beyond.       
    11 |  */
  > 12 | export default function processAmount(number: number, displayedInFeed: boolean): string {
       |                                                                                  ^
    13 |
    14 |         // turns "2707" -> "2,707" and "306438" -> "306k"
    15 |     // console.log(number
```

My understanding is that if I put `: string {` after declaring function parameters the way I did, I should get no bugs.

It may be something to do with not having a tsconfig file. I'm not sure though. Experts please!

Please note, [this did not help me understand my failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010695/function-lacks-ending-return-statement-and-return-type-does-not-include-undefin) and neither is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69240338/error-in-typescript-function-function-lacks-ending-return-statement-and-return). I'm just a bit too newb at TS.

When I resolve the error I'm looking for `tsc processAmount.ts` to compile the program into js. However, that doesn't work either, it says:

```
error TS6053: File 'processAmount.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

What to do?

Comment: Think about the control flow: what if none of the conditions are true?

Comment: @DaveNewton technically not possible here. However, TS doesn't analyse that the `if/else` chain covers all possibilities.

Comment: @VLAZ I know, but I was trying to nudge :) (Does the latest TS catch this? I know there have been improvements in analyses "depth".)

Comment: @DaveNewton I also know but I think that's what was tripping OP up. Expecting that all the cases *are* all the cases. EDIT: [and latest still doesn't catch it](https://tsplay.dev/WPxjEW)

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637515/why-cant-typescript-infer-the-return-type-when-using-differentiating-type-checks

Comment: The accepted answer to the above explains what you are experiencing.

Comment: @VLAZ Hm, beta doesn't either. I mean, I'm not terribly *surprised*, and IIRC the biggest improvement was looking harder for the null-checks (or sthng alone those line), but still :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, generally you're right, TypeScript shouldn't mark it as an error because your `if` statements cover all possible cases but TypeScript isn't *that* smart. Easiest solution to satisfy it is to just replace the last condition `else if (amtAsString.length > 6) {` with just `else`. It will work exactly the same (as all other possible cases are covered earlier) and TypeScript won't complain.

Nitpick and slightly off topic: you don't actually need `:string` in `const amtAsString: string`, TypeScript will infer the type automatically from the assigned value.